# Birt Report - Getting extra page

Tags: birt

I created a simple report with a header, a chart, and a small table.  It looks good in the preview but when I run it with the web viewer it says the report is 2 pages and has a blank second page.

Does anyone know how I might disable this blank second page?

Comment: Check page break attributes of your tables and grids. I have fixed similar issue by setting 'Page break interval' to zero for some of my reports.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going to the master page, and going to the advanced settings. I set orientation to portrait and overflow to hidden.  I'm not sure which change did it, but it's fixed now.